# C#: generate RANDOM numbers between two limits IN ORDER

Tags: c#, random, double

I want to generate random (double) numbers between two limits, let say: lim1 and lim2.

But, I want this numbers to be generated in order. E.g.: between 1 and 6 : 1.53412 1.654564 2.213123 5.13522 . Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far and why isn't your current solution working? Please post some code.

Comment: Well, you could generate some numbers and then sort them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static double[] GenerateRandomOrderedNumbers(double lowerBoundInclusive, double upperBoundExclusive, int count, Random random = null)
{
    random = random ?? new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count)
        .Select(i => random.NextDouble() * (upperBoundExclusive - lowerBoundInclusive) + lowerBoundInclusive)
        .OrderBy(d => d)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Not perfect, but I hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd pass in the `Random` instance as a parameter, to avoid seeding issues.

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't generate numbers between two limits. Easy enough fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the random numbers and put them on a list:

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
Random random = new Random();
```

Add your numbers:

```
var number = random.Next(min, max); 
numbers.Add(number);
```

Then sort the list:

```
var orderList = from n
  in numbers
  orderby n
  select n;
```

Comment: `Random.Next` returns `int`s, the OP wants doubles.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this to generate a set of random numbers:

```
lim1 + random.Next(lim2 - lim1)
```

and then simply sorting them?

## See also:

- [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681)